# MVC form post action works locally but gives error 404 on web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 application I am declaring a form on view with following syntax

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmRegistration" }))
```

& here is the form's post action method **Create**

```
 public ActionResult Create(VirtuOx.Models.Admin.Register AccInfo)
    {
        string errMessage = ValidateFields(AccInfo);
        ModelState.Clear();
        if (errMessage == "")
        {
            byte[] unsaltedPassword = Signin.StrToByteArray(AccInfo.Password);
            byte[] saltValue;
            byte[] saltedPassword = Signin.GeneratePassword(unsaltedPassword, out saltValue);

            //pharmacy superuser password
            byte[] PHARM_unsaltedPassword = Signin.StrToByteArray(AccInfo.SuperUserPassword ?? "");
            byte[] PHARM_saltValue;
            byte[] PHARM_saltedPassword = Signin.GeneratePassword(PHARM_unsaltedPassword, out PHARM_saltValue);

            string _membershipexpirationdate = (string)DB.ExecuteScalar("ConnectionString", "pc_GetConfigurationValue", new SqlParameter("@Code", "MembershipExpirationDate"));

            VirtuOx.Models.Customer.Register custRegister = new VirtuOx.Models.Customer.Register(AccInfo.VendorAccountID, AccInfo.UserName, Convert.ToBase64String(saltedPassword),
                                            Convert.ToBase64String(saltValue), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(AccInfo.MembershipType),
                                            _membershipexpirationdate, AccInfo.FirstName, AccInfo.LastName, AccInfo.CompanyName, AccInfo.Email,
                                            AccInfo.Street, AccInfo.City, AccInfo.State, "US", AccInfo.PostalCode,
                                            AccInfo.WorkPhone ?? "", AccInfo.Fax ?? "", AccInfo.ReportFax ?? "", AccInfo.Cell ?? "", AccInfo.CustomerRole,
                                            AccInfo.PhysicianID ?? 0, AccInfo.HierarchyLevelID ?? 0, Convert.ToInt32(AccInfo.EnableHST),
                                            Convert.ToInt32(AccInfo.EnablePST), Convert.ToInt32(AccInfo.EnableHSTRecommendations),
                                            Convert.ToInt32(AccInfo.EnableDocumentationEmail), 1, 1, 1, 1, Convert.ToInt32(AccInfo.EnableWireless),
                                            (AccInfo.CustomerRole != "12" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(AccInfo.CompanyID)),
                                            Convert.ToBase64String(PHARM_saltedPassword), Convert.ToBase64String(PHARM_saltValue),
                                            AccInfo.ParentID ?? 0);


            WebProfile response = custRegister.RegisterCustomer();
            if (response.Type == "S")
            {
                ViewBag.SuccessMessage = response.Text;
                ModelState.Clear();                    
            }
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("ExpAccount", response.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Exception", errMessage);
        }
        AccInfo.StateList = Common.GetStates();
        AccInfo.RoleList = Common.GetRoleTypes();
        AccInfo.CompanyList = Common.GetCustomerBranchList();
        AccInfo.ParentList = Common.GetReferenceList("PARENTID");
        AccInfo.HierarchyLevelList = Common.GetReferenceList("HIERARCHY");
        return View("~/Views/Admin/Register.cshtml", AccInfo);
    }
```

On my local machine this form is working perfectly for form's post action method **Create**. But when I deploy it on web server & if I click submit button it gives me error 404. I guess there should not be any problem with the code as it is working fine locally.

Comment: What is in Form action attribute on the rendered form? Is it correct? Also, ensure all files were copied to the web server

Comment: @jim thanks for your replay, all files are uploaded correctly. & action attribute has value "/Admin/Create".

Comment: @jim Hi, can you look at the way I solve this issue & brief me about how those attribute of Html.BeginForm() can create such problem.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem by changing the form definition as follows

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Admin"))
```

I removed the FormMethod attribute & HTML attribute object; which solves my problem.
But I did not understand how this attributes specification can create 404 error in shared hosting environment.

Comment: let us see what the difference between old and new rendered FORM tag